# Standard error of the residuals for a non-linear model

Tags: standard-error, nonlinear-regression

Hi I am new to R and statistics and used to linear models. Can you please explain the output? I used it to make a growth curve.

```
Formula: length ~ a * (1 - exp(-c * est_age))

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a 1.097e+03  1.026e+01 106.966  < 2e-16 ***
c 1.539e-01  1.982e-02   7.765 2.33e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 41.74 on 38 degrees of freedom
Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.32e-07
```

Comment: Spelling out which R function you used is always good practice.

Comment: More information would help. Would you understand the meaning of the column headings if it were a linear regression model rather than a nonlinear model? Would you understand some but not others?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you're using `nls`.

By typing

```
?summary.nls
```

you can read about the output.

Estimates and standard errors are estimated by the Gauss-Newton algorithm (if the `nls` defaults are used)

The P-values are the results of a two sided test of whether the parameters are zero or not.

You can check the exact calculations used to create the output shown by typing:

```
stats:::summary.nls
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to type "two-sided" instead of "one-sided"?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks, well spotted. @whuber, you really pop up everywhere with good responses

Comment: The model fitted is not logistic. It grows from 0 and approaches an upper asymptote exponentially.

Comment: Is it not? I labelled it logistic because it is a specific version of the [generalised logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function)

Comment: Really? A glance at the algebra suggests otherwise. In any case, I'd assert that as usually understood in growth modelling  a logistic curve has an inflexion.

Comment: You are right, there is no division, I'm going blind